# HTML5 Video OnComplete Next Slide Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, reveal.js

Does anyone know if one can connect a HTML5 Video with the presentation javascript, Reveal.js so that if I play a video on one slide, when that video is complete, it would automatically progress to the next slide?

Reveal.js has it's own eventHandler

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'customevent', function() {
    console.log( '"customevent" has fired' );
} );
```

But I cannot find any specific documentation on if elements inside a slide can trigger the nextSlide functionality.

Answer (score 3):

SO... here is the solution, or at least the answer that I came up with.

You have a series of SECTIONS that are acting as the slides, and a video in one of those slides.

in THAT slide, you need to add the following script:

```
<script>
     var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
     video.onended = function(e) {
          Reveal.next();
     }
</script>
```

Make sure you label your video element with an ID tag, and then call that ID tag in this script. The Reveal.next() is part of the built-in API that will automatically progress the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

For background videos things get a little more complex, because those cannot be given (AFAIK) a unique ID. I got it to work like this:

```html
<section
  data-background-video="thevideo.webm"
  data-state="next-after-video"
></section>
```

With this script added to the bottom of the page, after the call to `Reveal.initialize()`:

```js
function register_video_onend(may_retry_later) {
  let video = document.querySelector(".slide-background.present video");
  if (video == null) {
    if (!may_retry_later) {
      console.log("no video found");
      return;
    }
    window.setTimeout(register_video_onend, 1);
    return;
  }
  console.log("video found, will go to next slide when it ends");
  video.onended = (e) => {
    console.log("going to next slide after video ended");
    Reveal.next();
  };
}

Reveal.addEventListener("next-after-video", () =>
  register_video_onend(true)
);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works based on the `data-state` attribute of the slide. In other words, if you have multiple slides that all need this feature, you only have to add `data-state="next-after-video"` to them and it'll work.